# FSGetCatalogInfoBulk() slower on APFS than HFS+

Tags: macos, macos-carbon, macos-high-sierra

Has anyone else noticed that FSGetCatalogInfoBulk() is much slower on the new APFS compared to the traditional HFS+? If yes, is there any reason for this, and can we improve it on APFS?

Answer (score 0):

`FSGetCatalogInfoBulk()` is part of the Carbon File Manager APIs, which have all been deprecated since OS X 10.8. These work on APFS volumes but in a compatibility/legacy mode, so performance may suffer. You should use supported APIs like [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager)